# Type TAB in text area using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Recenty I migrated from Selenium RC to Webdriver. Typing text containing delimiter TAB used to work fine on Selenium RC. But when using webdriver, typing tab moves focus to next input.

Sample text :

```
Name    Age
Mark    35
```

I did the following :

```
    if(text.contains("\t"))
    {
      data = text.split("\t");
      for (String str : data)
      {
        element.sendKeys(str);
        element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
      }
    }
    else
    {
      element.sendKeys(text);
    }
```

I tried using `elements.sendKeys("\t")` as well as `elements.sendKeys("\\t")`.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you send a TAB key in a text field, if not move to the next input.

Comment: The sample text specified in the question needs to be typed as it is in the text area.

Comment: Can you do it manually? Like opening a browser typing "Mark" and then pressing the TAB key without moving to the next input field?

Comment: Ummm no.. but I can paste data. So does that mean I can only paste data and not type it in the text area?

Comment: Selenium Webdriver helps you mimic user interaction. It wont allow you to do what you cannot do manually. That is the golder rule imk. So as you suggested copy pasting could be one way to handle this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Actions class for advanced operations. Refer this site  http://www.guru99.com/keyboard-mouse-events-files-webdriver.html

Comment: Thanks for the source. To paste data in the text area using context menu, I could use `Actions action = new Actions(driver);  action.contextClick(element).sendKeys(Keys.ARROW_DOWN).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN).build().perform();` But how do i copy text to clipboard?

Comment: To copy text to clipboard, `Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(new StringSelection(text), null); element.sendKeys(Keys.CONTROL + "v");` where variable text contains data to be pasted in the text area.

Comment: it's a good idea to quote the relevant parts of the third party link. if the link goes down for any number of reasons your answer will make little to no sense

Answer (score 1):

As already said in the comments, the use of `sendKeys` will work as if you were a normal user of the browser. That means the browser will focus on the next input. If you really need to add a TAB in the input, I think the solution is to [execute JavaScript](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?).

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('" + inputId + "').value = '\\t';");
```